# $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ $\implies$ $||f(x_1,y_1)||=||f(x_2,y_2)||$

Tags: vector-analysis

How is the following shown:

$$f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2) \implies ||f(x_1,y_1)||=||f(x_2,y_2)||$$

?

That is, that if two elements are equivalent, then their norms are equivalent.

Comment: A norm is a function, and functions are single-valued (i.e., well-defined)...?

Comment: Definition of equality.

Comment: Hmm perhaps, confused about the norm notation, when it could be $|\cdot|$ here.